# Text Content Relevancy Check

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, topic-modeling

[image: Amazon.in pic]

I need to check relevancy of content on particular web page. I have thousands of
  webpages to check this on. What is the best way to check if the page title is relevant to the content on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit vague, when you say:

> What is the best way to check if the page title is relevant to the
>   content on the page.

How is being relevant defined in the context of your problem?

I don't know if this is what you want, but couple of thing come to my mind, which essentially is comparing how similar two documents are, being one document the title and the other the description.

You can think about methods to generate vector representations for both and compare how similar they are.

1. Jaccard similarity using the tokens as elements of the both sets (i.e., documents)
2. TF-IDF weighted vectors and compare them with cosine similarity
3. Compute distribution topic model/LDA for each document and compare them using Kullback-Leibler divergence
4. Encode the documents into some sort of dense vector (doc2vec, or read them through an LSTM and keep the last state), and then compare both vectors.

The only consideration is that the size of the title is very small compared to the content of the webpage.